# How do you walk and shoot?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Micro question: Stalker vs Zealot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7745/micro-question-stalker-vs-zealot)

How do you walk and shoot in Starcraft 2? For example, marines can seems like they are shooting while walking. How do you do it? Just right click, <kbd>H</kbd>, right click, <kbd>H</kbd>, right click, <kbd>H</kbd> really fast?

With Stalkers and Immortals it's fairly easy, I just walk them, target/focus fire a unit and move again, since they have pretty long delay between rounds of attacks.

Can't get it to look smooth with marines though. And it doesn't seem like they're target firing anything, when I see someone else do it.

Explain anybody?

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7745/micro-question-stalker-vs-zealot - Even though it's harder with Marines it's still the same concept.

Comment: The other question indeed cover this one; in particular, it explains what technique is used to achieve that shoot-and-walk effect without focus-firing.