# How to counter MMM-ball + Siege tanks as Zerg?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-terran

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't beat Terran as Zerg when they do MMM with a splash of tanks, any ideas?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7568/i-cant-beat-terran-as-zerg-when-they-do-mmm-with-a-splash-of-tanks-any-ideas)

What's the best combination of units as Zerg against MMM + Siege tanks behind them?

With banelings u won't get close enough to do damage and pretty much any other massed unit (roaches/hydras/mutas) won't do enough damage considering the medivacs and siege tanks.

Any suggestion appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7568/i-cant-beat-terran-as-zerg-when-they-do-mmm-with-a-splash-of-tanks-any-ideas Try looking there. Tzenes has a great answer for it.

Comment: No problem.  Humorously though, with the rep I gained from this answer, I gained comment privileges. :-/